# Session Id changes on each page refresh in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails sets a session by default for each user by the name specified in session_store.rb. These are my contents of session_store.rb file .

TestApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_test_app_session'

I think this is encrypted(please correct if wrong) using the contents of this file. secret_token.rb. The file's contents are :

require 'securerandom'

```
def secure_token
  token_file = Rails.root.join('.secret')
  if File.exist?(token_file)
    # Use the existing token.
    File.read(token_file).chomp
  else
    # Generate a new token and store it in token_file.
    token = SecureRandom.hex(64)
    File.write(token_file, token)
    token
  end
end
TestApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = secure_token
```

The problem is my session **_test_app_session** contents changes every time the page is refreshed. Can someone tell me why ? Also , if it changes then how should I make the session value change stop ?

Also, Why does rails need to set session by default ?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model This might be able to help? I don't know what you're trying to accomplish to be honest

Comment: I have a rails application and a Php application. I want to set a session when the user lands on rails application so that the user is not treated as a new one when he goes to the Php application. That is it.

Comment: Ohhh. That's like mixing wine & beer expecting to get the same result - it's hard for no reason. Can I ask why you're trying to blend PHP & Rails? This kind of thing is normally solved with an API if the apps are independent, or if they're on the same server, they're normally coded in the same language / framework & can communicate

Comment: @Egalitarian after 6 years :D. I am also stuck how to stop changing value of session? Did you find why it is behaving like this and how to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that rails creates a session by default. From what I know sessions are lazy in rails. You won't get a session cookie set unless you manipulate the `session` variable in your application (or some gem does that).

I'm still not quite sure why the value of the session changes. I think it's because of a timestamp that indicates the lifetime of a session, but I did not find evidence of that. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028015/why-does-the-rails-session-cookie-change-with-each-request